# HTML Create menu across frame

Tags: html, menu

Our application’s homepage is divided into frames.
There are 3 frames. Top, Middle and bottom.
We have to create menu in top frame. We tried creating menu in top frame, however it adds scroll bar to top frame page, instead of overlapping in 2nd frame.

Here is the code.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html> 
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"> <title>Some title</title>  
</head>

<frameset rows="8%,*,25%">
   <frame src="frame_a.htm" border="0" frameborder="0" >
  <frame src="frame_b.htm" border="0" frameborder="0" >
  <frame src="frame_c.htm" border="0" frameborder="0" > 
</frameset>     


</html>
```

### frame_b.htm

```
<html>
    <body>
        This is frame b
    </body>
</html>
```

### frame_c.htm

```
<html>
    <body>
        This is frame b
    </body>
</html>
```

### frame_a.html

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

Can somebody please help here, how this can be done?

Thanks,
Hiren

Comment: Post what you have tried?

Comment: You should provide some code for us to look at. We cant just guess what you have already.

Comment: Well actually I wanted to add image here, however due to less reputation, stackoverflow is not allowing me to add image.

Comment: Hi Govan, Ruddy, I have added the code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In theory: You could detect the frame size and scroll position to see if the menu will overlap the border. If it does, you navigate though `top.frames.etc` to the other frame and create a duplicate menu there positioning it based on the size and scroll position of the other frame.

In practise, you'd be better off ditching the frames entirely. They are almost always far more trouble then they are worth.

Comment: Actually I also don't like frames. However since this is a legacy application, that is not the option. Also if we create copy in second frame, it would be like repeating in every page.

Comment: @user3030664 — yes, but you want it to appear in every page.

Comment: Yes, but it would be like a duplication of code in all other sub frame pages. I wish there could be other solution.